# c# linq add a column to a new list from another single column list

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

My project is MVC5. I have a table with multiple rows for the same day, I need to get the total of this entry for each day, I use the following:

```
var days = db.Nutrition.Where(x => x.Day >= fromDate 
           && x.Day <= toDate).DistinctBy(x => x.Day).AsEnumerable().ToList();
List<double?> calories = new List<double?>();
foreach (var item in days)
{
    calories.Add(days.Where(c => c.Day==item.Day).Select(x => x.Calories).Sum());
}
```

I get a list containing the totals.  Now I need to make a new list that has two columns.
I made the following model:

```
public class Consumption
{ 
    public virtual double? Calories { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I tried to use the following to generate the new list:

```
 List<Consumption> newList = new List<Consumption>();
 var name = new Consumption { Name = "name" };
 foreach (var item in calories)
 {
     newList.Add(name, Calories = (double)item.Value);
 }
```

I get the following error:

> The name 'Calories' does not exist in the current context

**Edit**

Thanks to Stephen's comment:
I just used one line to achieve same result

```
var results = db.Nutrition.Where(x => x.Day >= fromDate && x.Day <= toDate).GroupBy(l => l.Day)
         .Select(cl => new { Name = "name", Calories = cl.Sum(c => c.Calories)}).ToList();
```

Comment: newList.Add(new Consumption { Name = "name", Calories = (double)item.Value });

Comment: It would need to be `newList.Add(new Consumption{ Name = "name", Calories = (double)item.Value });` but it not really clear what you want to achieve - and there is a lot of inefficient/pointless code

Comment: Thank you both for your answers. @StephenMuecke I am using the result to generate chart using Ajax and Knockout.

Comment: Then I assume you want the sum for each day? In which case you can simply use a `.GroupBy()` Although its not clear what `Name` (or why you just hard code it)

Comment: Thank you, I will try .GroupBy().  Name is used for the ko.observableArray([]) I am using for chart series.

Comment: Yes, but what is the value of `Name` - I assume you want it to be `Day`?

Comment: Good point, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
List<Consumption> newList = new List<Consumption>();
var name = new Consumption { Name = "name" };
foreach (var item in calories)
{
    var cal = new Consumption{ Name = "name", Calories = (double)item.Value });
    newList.Add(cal);
}
```

Comment: I initially downvoted this, but I'm going to reset it.  please explain your answer and the issue with OP's code. "Try With: <snippet>" isn't an answer, it is a comment. @hncl refrain from marking answers like this as accepted, when it was really the commentator in your question that provided the quality answer you accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You received this compiler error

> The name 'Calories' does not exist in the current context

because the `List<Consumption>.Add(Comsumption item)` method on your variable `newList` only accepts one argument of type `Consumption`.

---

Regarding your intentions, and the discussion in your comments with @StephenMuecke, it became clear that your intention is to `Sum` a property `double Calories`, and `GroupBy` by property `DateTime Day` and then **project** that into a `List<Consumption>`.

```
var dateTimeFormat = "yyyy-dd-MM"; 
var results = db.Nutrition.Where(x => x.Day >= fromDate && x.Day <= toDate)
    .GroupBy(x => x.Day)
    .Select(groupedX => new Consumption 
    { 
        Name = groupedX.Key.ToString(dateTimeFormat), 
        Calories = groupedX.Sum(y => y.Calories) 
    }).ToList();
```